# How to add Windows mouse hover effect using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, windows-10, taskbar, mousehover

I have recently noticed that *amazing* **hover effect** that Microsoft added in Windows 10 on `Tiles`, `Taskbar` and `Settings`!
Is it possible to do that using HTML, CSS and JS! Please tell me along with a proper Code

[image]

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried so far an if you are facing any specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

After a quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%2010%20tile%20effect%20html) I was able to find this for you;

https://github.com/MaxMls/CSS-Windows-10-Tile

Demo here;

https://maxmls.github.io/CSS-Windows-10-Tile/

I'm sure with some tweaking you can get it to work how you like

Comment: Thanks Brother ☺️☺️

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, great job :)

Answer (score 0):

Just about 2 years ago only, I developed my logic for re-creating these windows effects using JS and CSS (without canvas API and advanced CSS) and created this blog series [Recreating Windows 10 Effects using HTML, CSS, and vanilla JS](https://dev.to/jashgopani/series/12364). Based on the same logic, I also developed this [react-win-grid](https://github.com/jashgopani/react-win-grid) library which has these tile components.